# Google App Engine Java with mvn devserver failed: missing "guestbook/target/guestbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm trying to go through the simple [tutorial on Google App Engine with Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code), but when I try to run the `mvn appengine:devserver` command, I get this weird missing directory error:

```
[INFO] guestbook ......................................... FAILURE [  0.228 s]
[INFO] guestbook-war ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] guestbook-ear ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.446 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-06T12:03:51-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/176M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:devserver (default-cli) on project guestbook: The application directory does not exist : /Users/davidt/GoogleAppEngineProjects/guestbook/target/guestbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

What is going on? When was I supposed to have created that snapshot?

Note: I am not sure if this matters, but I've been deleting and recreating the project multiple times under the same folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to run `mvn appengine:devserver` in the `guestbook-ear` folder. I was running it on the top level.

Comment: what if you don't have the ear folder?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  the pom.xml file is in the root folder. Can you elaborate?  do I need to cd into the ear directory, and then invoke mvn to  explicitly refer to the pom in the parent directory ?  (Your example did not show this) 

Is this really what Google appenegine team intends? Is this documented?